# matlab mod conversion to c++

Tags: c++, matlab

this is cornerX

```
    [0] 1041.0374994748950  double
    [1] 2489.4116123346407  double
    [2] 1029.5005409900616  double
    [3] 2477.8746538498076  double
```

CornerY

```
    [0] 834.69193966025080  double
    [1] 852.22774706647908  double
    [2] 1787.5897232339489  double
    [3] 1805.1255306401772  double
```

here is the original matlab function

```
cornerX=cornerX+(1-mod(cornerX,2));
cornerY=cornerY+(1-mod(cornerY,2));
```

here is my function

```
void AutomaticMacbethDetection::CalculateBatchCenters(std::vector<double> cornerX, std::vector<double> cornerY)
{

    cornerX=cornerX+(1-mod(cornerX,2));
    cornerY=cornerY+(1-mod(cornerY,2));*/
    for (int i = 0; i < cornerX.size(); i++)
    {
        cornerX[i] = cornerX[i] + (1 - (Utilities::realmod(cornerX[i],2.0)));
    }
```

here is my c++ modulu

```
double Utilities::realmod(double x, double y)
{
    if (y == 0 )
    {
        return x;
    }
    else if ( x == y)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        double n = floor(x/y);
        double result  = x - n *y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have created my function based on Matlab's description

```
MOD(x,y) is x - n.*y where n = floor(x./y) if y ~= 0.  If y is not an
%   integer and the quotient x./y is within roundoff error of an integer,
%   then n is that integer.  The inputs x and y must be real arrays of the
%   same size, or real scalars.
```

Can you explain why am I getting totally different results?
I guess I'm using the arrays wrong somehow...

Comment: @Gilad ,   on what data?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm I have added the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the difference is that you are passing the vector by value, not by reference.

Simple compare:

## Octave / MATLAB

http://ideone.com/53Sd2o

```
X = [1041.0374994748950
2489.4116123346407
1029.5005409900616
2477.8746538498076];
Y = [834.69193966025080  
852.22774706647908  
1787.5897232339489  
1805.1255306401772 ];
X+(1-mod(X,2))
Y+(1-mod(Y,2))
```

## C++

http://ideone.com/Xdi1ta

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>

double realmod(double x, double y);
void test(std::vector<double> &cornerX);
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> X = {1041.0374994748950,
    2489.4116123346407,
    1029.5005409900616,
    2477.8746538498076};

    std::vector<double> Y = {834.69193966025080 , 
    852.22774706647908  ,
    1787.5897232339489  ,
    1805.1255306401772 };
    test(X);
    test(Y);
    std::copy(X.begin(),X.end(),std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout,"\t"));
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::copy(Y.begin(),Y.end(),std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout,"\t"));
    return 0;
}


double realmod(double x, double y)
{
    if (y == 0 )
        return x;
    else if ( x == y)
        return 0.0;
    else
        return x - floor(x/y) *y;
}

void test(std::vector<double> &cornerX)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cornerX.size(); i++)
        cornerX[i] = cornerX[i] + (1 - realmod(cornerX[i],2.0));
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code, no this is not the problem. please have a look at my input

Comment: @Gilad,   changed test data,the results are the same. Look at the link.